# Flutter Recreating the Hero Transition replacing Navigator with a custom Animator

Tags: flutter, overlay, accordion, hero

Looking at the Flutter Hero Transition, it appears to move the tagged Widgets to an Overlay class that exists in all Navigator Widgets but sits above the main content in the stack.

If this is correct, it allows the Hero to widgets to still respond to the Route scope and its animators but exist above the actual route content. How is this actually done efficiently? Surely this involves taking an entire Widget and storing it in a state for the duration of the animation. That Widget still has to respond to intrinsic responses from its original position such as slivers responding to active scroll actions.

Recreating this could be done with state management but I wondered how the standard hero actually does this. It seems like Widgets are effectively duplicated and then conditionally rendered on the screen defaulting to the overlay during the route animation and swapping out the original widget with an Offstage or similar. Is this how it is done?

The reason for trying to understand it is the need to replicate this behaviour in situations where Navigator is not an effective use case for a transition taking place internally on a page. I built an accordion style navigator but still want a hero transition to take place on the AppBar / NavigationBar. I know that this could be done with Navigator but it doesn't suit the use case. I could also predefine the AppBar content for each internal navigator state of the accordion but that is a lot of additional code.